# ConEmu / Cmder - Drag Tab into New Window

Tags: conemu, cmder

In Cmder / ConEmu, I was working with multiple tabs, and realized it'd be helpful to have them side-by-side.  In Chrome/Firefox, I'd click a tab and drag it out of the parent window and release; it'll spawn a new window with just that tab.

I know I can detach the tab from ConEmu entirely, or spawn a new process in a new window, but I was trying to find a way to simply move an existing tab as-is to a new ConEmu window.

Answer (score 21):

This can be achieved by "Active Console -> Close or kill -> Unfasten" menu item (worked for me in 151115 alpha). Drag-n-drop feature is requested here: https://github.com/Maximus5/ConEmu/issues/346

Comment: Wow, the really have "Detach" and "Unfasten" hidden under the wrong menu item. I looked for this several times and never thought to look at the "Close or Kill" menu.

Comment: In case i haven't missed an update this is still valid in 2020

Answer (score 0):

I would find it useful too, but currently it is not possible to drag the tabs and detach them easily. 
You can just reorder them.

Is there issue filled already? https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/issues/